# ksuid genration return string in go

Tags: string, go, byte, encoder, ksuid

I am using below function to generate ksuid in byte format but i need it to return ksuid in string format.

I tried returning `id.string()` value but i am getting below error
error:
cannot use `id.String()` (value of type string) as `id_return` value in return statement.

I would like it to assign the return string value like below (string instead of byte)
`var id_gen string = genKsuid()`

```
type id []byte

type id_return string

func genKsuid() id {
    id, err := ksuid.NewRandomWithTime(time.Now())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ksuid:     %s\n", id.String())
    return id.Bytes()
}

var id_gen []byte = genKsuid()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to

```
func genKsuid() string {
    id, err := ksuid.NewRandomWithTime(time.Now())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ksuid:     %s\n", id.String())
    return id.String()
}
```

Comment: Great, you can accept this awnser by clicking the check mark near the post